# How can I configure a computer to connect to the internet through another computer that has two NICs?

Tags: networking

I use a hard wired connection from my box to my router, I have an older system without a wireless card and want to run it ad hoc.

My master box is a Dell Optiplex gx270 running Ubuntu 12.04. The box I want to connect through it is an HP pavilion 6740c running puppy 5.6.1.

I've tried to install wireless cards but I'm too far from the router. The dell has two NIC cards, so I wondered if I could configure the HP to connect through the Dell.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu MatthewW! I just want to double check: you have two computers, a Dell (connected to the router via cable), and an HP. The HP doesn't have wireless, and you would like it to connect to the internet by connecting it to the Dell's other NIC card, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this link. Bridge the cards on your Dell, and if you use dhcp it should be plug and play. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConnectionBridge